# Is there any graphical or code first database design support in Visual Studio 2019 for non-SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, database-design, visual-studio-2019

Does Visual Studio provide any way to design a database either graphically or code-first for any database other than SQL Server apart from Entity Framework?

I'm looking at starting a new database project, possibly using Postgres (I haven't quite decided), so I'm looking for some decent tooling that supports graphical and/or code-first design, with migration support between different versions.

My inclination is to give Entity Framework a miss. I've used it before and found the abstraction to be at such a high level that it was more of a hindrence than a help when it came to optimizing and diagnosing performance issues.

I'm quite happy to use Dapper for my data access but some tooling to simplify design, versioning and migration would be very useful. If Visual Studio has some support for this I might as well check it out since I'll be using Visual Studio elsewhere on the project anyway, but I don't see anything useful in the docs.

If Visual Studio isn't going to be useful in this regard is there anything you'd recommend? Something that works with most of the main DB systems would be preferable instead of something that just works with one system.

Comment: If you don't want to use SQL Server and entity framework then I suggest you don't use Visual Studio. Not sure what else you would use though. I'm curious as to the reasoning to not use SQL Server? There are free versions.

Comment: I don't have any personal aversion to using SQL Sever it's just that when it comes to hosted systems you may find a better deal if you are not tied to a single system.

Comment: If you're planning on trying to go multi database platform, that's a hard road. Implementation and maintenance is often easier of you pick a single 'ecosystem'

Comment: I'm not planning to support multiple platforms for a single project, or even to switch platforms during development, I'm just looking for some decent design and versioning tooling that has some flexibility and doesn't tie me into a single DB system before I'm ready to make that decision.